# Tomcat 6 restoring sessions even when no cookie exists

Tags: session, tomcat, persistence

What started as an annoyance now has me concerned.

I was testing a web app, logged in under one user account. I closed the broswer, recycled the server, opened a new browser and flushed the cache, then logged in using a different account.

Inspection of the "new" session revealed that the previous session (and all session data) had been restored even though there should have been no cookie available to identify the user.

Is Tomcat restoring the session based on the IP address and remote user from the header? If so, can this behavior be disabled, short of disabling session persistence altogether?

Comment: Did you explicitly clear out the cookies from the browser? This is normally a separate operation to clearing the cache. It's possible that a combination of persistent cookies and persistent sessions are being used. Worth having a look at the application code - to see whether it's doing anything over and above default session creation. Also worth checking the Tomcat server.xml to see whether there's any special config for the session manager (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) which may cause sessions to be long-lived.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that Tomcat's session manager can do this - even with configuration. Tomcat only uses the ID to identify the session and without the cookie or session ID in the URL Tomcat 6 can't map the request to the old session.

You need to look at what the application is doing and or any customisations that have been applied to your Tomcat installation.